# I need some clarification on GET and POST concerning JQuery AJAX and MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, postback

I am wondering if it is an all-or-nothing situation. What I would like to do, Load (GET) my page by normal MVC 3. Controller takes Model and passes it to View. View and Razor render it. However, when I post back, I'd like it to postback the selected info through AJAX. Is this possible? Or do I have do GET and POST with AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly POST using AJAX after GETting using other means.

Here's a random question on SO that does just this:

[Ajax post in MVC 3 with multiple-form View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999703/ajax-post-in-mvc-3-with-multiple-form-view)

The GET and POST actions do not have to be related at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the below.
Controller Code:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult WhateverActionName()
    {
        YourViewModel yvm = new YourViewModel();
        //Initalize viewmodel here
        Return view(yvm);
    }
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult WhateverActionName(YourViewModel yvm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        RedirectToAction("OtherAction", "OtherController")
    }
    return View(yvm);
}
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: myurl
    // processData: false, // you may need this option depending on service setup
    success: function(){
        location.href = "TARGET LOCATION";
    },
    type: "POST"
});
```

For target location: You're going to need to feed the ajax a variable containing whatever URL the following generates

```
@URL.Action("Action", "Controller")
```

Answer (score 0):

http://knockoutmvc.com offers an nice way of integrating server side code with client side and it looks like it might help you easily achieve what you want.

Comment: Please never use Knockout MVC. Sending calls to the server for every function is wasteful.

Comment: i second that motion re knockoutmvc - don't do it- ever -please, pretty please...