# KnockOut.js With Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

Just started learning the new asp.net mvc4 SPA template , noticed that knockout is being used , so give me reference to any book / Video which describes asp.net mvc with knockout.js from scratch .

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A really good start is to work through the tutorials step by step on the [knockoutjs.com](http://knockoutjs.com/) site, the tutorials are brilliantly put together and there are live examples which help to demonstrate "real world" scenarios.

Once you are comfortable with the knockout constructs this [article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=847) gives a basic but good illustration of integrating pure knockout with MVC controllers, models and views.

An alternative approach is to use [knockoutMVC](http://knockoutmvc.com) although it is important to point out that this is an *extension* of knockout.js and is definitely not required to get knockout working really well in an MVC project (I don't use this but thought I would include for completeness).

Finally if you want to get more advanced, this [SPA guide](http://cgeers.com/2012/10/06/single-page-application-with-knockout-js-part-) is a very useful 4-part tutorial on creating a Single Page Application with Knockout and MVC.

Comment: But is there any tutrial in which they told about mvc and knockout ?

Comment: Hmm , gud . Lets see if anyone else have some thing much better

Comment: @user2413182 updated with a SPA specific link

Comment: its not 3-part , its actually 4-part . Anyway thank for another good share :-)

Comment: Awesome link (SPA) . Many Many thanks , almost contains every thing need for a great web . Thanks again . you've got +1 .

Comment: it is probably advisable to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618042/is-there-a-reason-i-would-use-knockout-mvc-instead-of-knockout-js before deciding on knockoutmvc.
Its misleading when you say `try this site for details on integrating knockout with MVC controllers, models and views:` <-- as youre implying knockoutjs requires  knockoutmvc to work with MVC which it doesnt and in fact knockoutmvc may be a *bad* way to combine the two.

Comment: @wal, I completely agree with you, that part of the answer is misleading. I will revise later on when I have time to update properly

Comment: @wal updated to be more transparent regarding knockoutmvc, thanks for your comments.