# mvc + knockout: how to initialize knockout data from model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am new to knockout and mvc (.net). I worked previosly with webforms.

I have read much and I understand "pure" knockout. I also understand "pure" MVC.

The question is how to use MVC model properites values to initialize knockout model?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832600/knockout-js-with-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628938/best-practice-on-passing-mvc-model-to-knockoutjs/11636746#11636746

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are passing a ViewModel which display an owner and list of cars he owns.
That is if we are passing a Person (id, firstName, lastName, age) object and a collection of Cars (id, person_id, make, color), we initialize it like

```
var vm = {};
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var personJSON = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.person));
    var carsJSON = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Cars));
    var PersonCarsViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.person = ko.observable(personJSON);
        self.cars = ko.observableArray(carsJSON);
    }
    vm = new PersonCarsViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

Please remember that

> An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array, not the state of those objects

That means if you have to update contents of cars you should make it an `observableArray` of `ko.observable`

Comment: What if my model has property Model.Type (that is some string) and also has a collection Model.Persons? Then if I use var modelJson = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); can I get somehow "persons" from modelJSON json string? Os should I write one mor etime personJson = ... Model.Persons?

Comment: could you elaborate it as a question and pass me the link? please provide a dummy model also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766491/get-mvc-person-model-book-list-within-knockout-model

Answer (score 2):

```
var myKnockoutViewModel = new MyKnockoutViewModel('@Model.PropertyOne', '@Model.PropertyTwo');
ko.applyBindings(myKnockoutViewModel, document.getElementById('myId'));
```

Comment: I have found even better option:  var vm = new viewModel(@(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model))));
    ko.applyBindings(vm);

Comment: If you have a large Model, it makes more sense to do it that way, yes.