# Get MVC Person Model book list within knockout model (observable array)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

What is the best practice to get MVC Model parameters within knockout Model?

*1) If you need to get just one parameter, you can use the following to set up knockout view model property:*

```
this.firstName = @Model.FirstName;
```

*2) If you have a bunch of properties wihtin a model, you can do the following:*

```
var modelData = function () { return @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); }();
```

and then later use

```
this.firstName = modelData.FirstName;
this.lastName = modelData.LastName;
this.phoneNumber = modelData.PhoneNumber; 
etc.
```

*3) What if you have some Collection within Person model. What is the best way to get the collection out of the person model?*

For example, Person has FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber etc. and has a **List of Books** (each book has tile, author and other properties).

I believe you can use seomething like this:

```
var booksJSON = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Books));
```

and then in the knockout Person model use:

```
self.books = ko.observableArray(booksJSON);
```

This gives only Books.

But what if I want to get all information about Person (Books, including FirstName, LastName, Phone and a bunch of properties), what is the best way to do this? Can I somehow use `Json.Encode` for the whole Person model and then get out of there everything, including Person.Books or should I split it into multiple `Json.Encode-s`??

Answer (score 2):

All data what you need should be in your C# Model. Then in knockout viewModel you should parse this data. For example:

C#

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public List<Book> Books {get;set}
} 

public class Book
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}        
}
```

Html, you should convert your C# model to json:

```
function (ko, ViewModel) {
     ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(@Html.Raw(Model.ToJson())), document.getElementById('Container'));
});
```

Knockout viewModel:

```
function ViewModel(model) {
    var self = this;

    self.FirstName = ko.observable(model.FirstName);
    self.LastName = ko.observable(model.LastName);
    self.Books = ko.observableArray(model.Books); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a simple (one-way) binding, this will do

```
var PersonViewModel = {};
$(function () {
    var personJSON = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    PersonViewModel = ko.observable(personJSON);
    ko.applyBindings(PersonViewModel, $("#person-container").get(0));
});
```

But if you want a two-way binding, ie, you wanna post back changes to the existing array back to server, you wanna make all properties in the object array `ko.observable`. That's because, as per knockoutjs documentation,

> Simply putting an object into an observableArray doesn’t make all of
>   that object’s properties themselves observable. Of course, you can
>   make those properties observable if you wish, but that’s an
>   independent choice. An observableArray just tracks which objects it
>   holds, and notifies listeners when objects are added or removed.

To make each object properties in the array `ko.observable`, we can use this generic function.

```
function MakeArrayKoObservableObjectArray(arr) {
    var observableArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var observableObj = {}, obj = arr[i];
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                observableObj[prop] = ko.observable(obj[prop]);
            }
        }
        observableArr.push(observableObj);
    }
    return observableArr;
}
```

Now we can use the function like this.

```
var personJSON = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
personJSON.Books = MakeArrayKoObservableObjectArray(personJSON.Books);
PersonViewModel = ko.observable(personJSON);
```