# KnockoutMVC submit button not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, knockout-mvc

I am using knockoutmvc to bind controls.(http://knockoutmvc.com/)

I am getting following error while clicking on button.

Following is my Razor view implementation :

```
@using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout

@model OpManWeb.ViewModel.ManageAddressVM

@{
    var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Manage Addresses";
}

@Scripts.Render("~/customjs")
@Scripts.Render("~/knockout")
<div class="container-fluid zeropadding" style="margin-top:15px; width:100%; font-size:13px;">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 clmargin">
            <div class="form-group  col-md-4 zeropadding div1adjustments">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IndexNo, new { @class = "fieldtext" })
            </div>
            <div class=" form-group col-md-8 div2adjustments ">
                @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.IndexNo, new { @class = "form-control input-sm fieldtextinput " })
                <input type="reset" class="btncross" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click to clear" value="X" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-search searchbtn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
                        title="Search customer as per Index No">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
                @ko.Html.Button("Add Address", "AddAddress", "Customer", null, new { @class = "btn btn-large btn-primary" })
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Following is the code for CustomerController File

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ServiceStack.Mvc;
using OpManWeb.Models;
using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout;
using OpManWeb.ViewModel;
using MvcJqGrid;

namespace OpManWeb.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : KnockoutController
    {
        public ActionResult AddAddress()
        {
            AddressVM addressVM = new AddressVM();
            addressVM.selectmode = Mode.Add;
            return View("AddEditAddress", addressVM);
        }
     }
}
```

Following is ther error Html Response
[image: Error Response While Clicking on Button]

Comment: Well, you are executing an ajax call on the browser but return an html page from the controller. What result are you expecting? See here for an example what you are expected to provide in your controller: http://knockoutmvc.com/ClickCounter

Comment: Also, what you posted does not look like Bundle.config, could you please double check. Also could you please explain why Bundle.config is significant in your case?

Comment: Hi zespri,
Thanks for your reply.

I want to use ko.Html.Button as "Submit" button which can post the data as well as can open different view, if required. So how to achieve that?

Sorry for the bundleconfig confusion. The code is for Razor view file.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what ko.Html.Button is for.

Comment: Then can you tell me how can I achieve this? Can you provide a code snippet ?

Comment: That's hard to do with the description you provided. The code that you shown does not have a form. Your action method does not have parameters. One can only guess where you are going with this. For example you can look at this tutorial http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-4-handling-form-edit-and-post-scenarios it might be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable time. I am grateful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While using @Ko.Html.Button we must return Json Object From Controller Method like below.

```
public ActionResult AddAddress()
    {

        return Json(new { Url = Url.Action("Stock", "Inventory") });
    }
```

Comment: You can also use return Json(Model);

Comment: I tried this with an external url as string instead of url.action etc and it did not work. Too bad there is no time to refactor and remove kmvc for our project. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11618190/169714

Comment: yeah http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618042/is-there-a-reason-i-would-use-knockout-mvc-instead-of-knockout-js/11618190#11618190  It is true its really Bastard Child.:(